# TikZ: Creating Schematic Transit Maps

Tags: tikz-pgf

For quite some time I have been wondering if anybody has ever considered creating beautiful schematic public transit maps with TikZ. From this type of maps, I am providing a small snippet from the Brno map here:

[image]

Much to my surprise, performing intense searching in the internet, including the TikZ examples collection, did not lead me to anything useful yet. I am thus asking if anyone knows any resources available for schematic transit maps based on TikZ, which can serve as starting point for refinement and improvement.

If there is something already available as a starting point, I am of course more than happy to share all my proceedings, experiences and the output openly.

*[By the way, the example included in this question appears to be created with [cairographics](https://www.cairographics.org/), a C-based graphic library; so public transit maps based on a non-interactive graphic environment do not seem to be unrealistic.]*

Comment: You should include an MWE that demonstrates what you have done yourself and ask for help to improve your code.

Comment: Thanks @Sveinung for this request; actually, I have to open-heartedly admit that I do not have a MWE for this case yet; this is why I asked for a starting point if someone already has teckled the typical issues of creating maps like the one shown with its specific challenges.

If this is the case, then perfect; I would be more than happy to proceed from this starting point by openly sharing findings, potholes and first of all the output. If not, then please give me some time and I will create some first draft with my hitherto amateurish mastery of TikZ.

Comment: TikZ wouldn't really be good for this application, as the different lines don't join. For drawing topological maps you need an application that understands topology, so that you can drag stations and lines about so they reroute nicely. Wikipedia tutorial using Inkscape: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Graphics_Lab/Resources/Draw_topological_maps This video shows TfL making the London map with Adobe Illustrator https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raQ3o88SOiA An example programe is https://www.edrawsoft.com/subwaymap.php

Comment: This question was put on hold for being too broad. I consequently removed the questions that are based on specific features of the (generic) example by making the question more precise to ask for available starting points on the given issue.

Answer (score 3):

You might find this useful.  Double lines are drawn as a narrow line (white) drawn on top of a thick line (black).  In this case, I reversed the colors.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfsetinnerstrokecolor{blue}
\draw[thick,double,white] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\pgfsetinnerstrokecolor{red}
\draw[thick,double,white] (1,-1) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way for Kormylo's answer: using `shorten`. Advantage: it does not affect surrounding of 2 straight lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path 
(0,0)   coordinate (A)
(2,1.5) coordinate (B)
(0,1)   coordinate (C)
(2,0)   coordinate (D)
(intersection of A--B and C--D) coordinate (I);
\draw[red] (A)--(B);
\draw[blue,shorten >=1pt] (C)--(I);
\draw[blue,shorten >=1pt] (D)--(I);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```